# get root view's methods to be called on root views object when called from child views

Tags: objective-c

`RootView`  has a label, and a method which updates this label. There is also a number of views located inside container views. Any of these should be able to update this label. They do so by calling this method. I am able to call it from these subview-controllers, but it does not update the label. Calling it from the root view does update the label. I've read about delegates, but I haven't been successful in adding it. Is that the way I should do it, by delegates?

this is from the subView. Please correct me If i am wrong, but I suppose it doesn't work because it creates a new rootView, and not using the old one.

Storyboard image here: http://i58.tinypic.com/2e17j1e.jpg

```
[super viewDidLoad];
self.rootView = [[RootViewController alloc]init];
[self.rootView displaymessage:@"Hello sent from child"];
```

Comment: So, you are using a NavigationController. Two, in fact. This makes it complex.

Comment: The navigationController that you present from the MainView, is it a push or a modal segue?

Comment: Should I remove the navigation controllers? The segues are a custom segue, no animation at all. Did use push segues earlier, just didn't want the animation.

Comment: I would suggest you bring it back to push segue, and set the animated property as NO.

Comment: I am posting an edit in a couple of minutes

Comment: ok, thanks. I changed the segues, and trying to get it working now.

Comment: I have posted an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing is wrong. Calling `self.rootView = [[RootViewController alloc]init];` actually creates a new instance of `RootViewController`. Fortunaltely, `UIVIewController` holds a property called `presentingViewController` which represents the viewController which presented the child.

```
self.rootView = self.presentingViewController;
[self.rootView displaymessage:@"Hello sent from child"];
```

Or simply,

```
[(RootViewController*)self.presentingViewController displaymessage:@"Hello sent from child"];
```

Here's the [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/presentingViewController) to Apple's documentation regarding the `presentingViewController` property.

**EDIT:**

Looking at the complexity, of your storyboard, I would suggest you use `NSNotificationCenter` to change the label. Here's how:

In RootViewController's viewDidLoad, paste this code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(displaymessageFromNotification:) name:@"rootDisplayMessage" object:nil];
```

Then add the following method to RootViewController's .m file:

```
-(void)displaymessageFromNotification:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSDictionary *data = [notification userInfo];
    NSString *message = [data objectForKey:@"message"];

    [self displaymessage:message];
}
```

Then, from anywhere in the code where you want to display a message in the RootViewController, use these lines:

```
NSDictionary *dicMessage  = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"Your message here." forKey:@"message"];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"rootDisplayMessage" object:nil userInfo:dicMessage];
```

Comment: how do I add this? I don't understand what that would do. ` NSLog(@"%@",self.presentedViewController);`outputs null

Comment: Replace the second and third line from the code you posted with the lines that I did.

Comment: This would call the displayMethod on the RootViewController, which presented the child viewController.

Comment: it is `presentingViewController`, not `presentedViewController`

Comment: oh, yeah, I tried both. Both are null. But I think it might be me using the wrong terms here. It is actually not a childView from code. I've added them in the storyboard in Xcode inside a container view

Comment: Could you post a snapshot of your storyboard?

Comment: You have subclassed UIView?

Comment: Not sure what subclassing is... Sorry.

Comment: Thank you so much. That last edit solved a lot of my problems.

Answer (score 0):

try some code like this:

//rootView add child controllers place

```
ChildControllers *childVc = [[ChildControllers alloc] init];
childVc.rootView = theRootViewAddChildVc;
```

//child controller.h

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) RootViewController * rootView;
```

//child controller.m update label place:

```
[self.rootView updateLabel];
```